# Change the content of the response after FastBoot has done its work

Tags: node.js, ember.js

I want to know if it's possible to change the content of the HTML response of FastBoot. I want to do some post processing in the code. I checked their code and they have a middleware ([fastboot-express-middleware](https://github.com/ember-fastboot/fastboot-express-middleware)) that looks promising.

Before diving more into the code I wanted to know if there is currently an approach that people usually use in their pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

1. Create an addon and specify to build after fastboot has processed its work in the package.json

```
"ember-addon": {
  "configPath": "tests/dummy/config",
  "after": [
    "ember-cli-fastboot"
  ],
}
```

2. There's a [PR](https://github.com/ember-fastboot/fastboot-express-middleware/pull/35) on hold on fastboot-express-middleware that should enable to add middleware's after fastboot is done